# Weakref has a different object_id?

Tags: ruby, weak-references

Why does a weakref of an object have a different object_id than the object itself?

**Main**

```
obj = {}
weakobj = WeakRef.new(obj)
puts weakobj.object_id
puts obj.object_id
```

**Output**

```
22206940
22207020
```

Why are the two numbers different?

Comment: They are different objects, and so they have different object_ids. From the docs on object_id: "no two active objects will share an id."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because they are both different object. 
Check the class of both `obj` and `weakobj` from console like `obj.class` and `weakobj.class`. You will see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

`obj` and `weakobj` are both objects.  They are not the same object.  And two different objects cannot share an ID